# GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am very concerned for this new alternative for development life-cycle.
Actually by this feature we are compiling Java file to Js in a super draft mode but what happens for very large projects that normal compilation takes over 45min (my last project) ?!
every time I change something in UI I should recompile all codes?!

Optimistic  speaking, it should take over 5mins to recompile in super mode!

Please let me know if I am wrong.
Regads,

Answer (score 4):

The difference between SuperDevMode and compiling in draft mode is that SuperDevMode uses a **resident compiler**, so it doesn't start from scratch when it needs to recompile your app. SuperDevMode also only compiles **one permutation** (the one that your browser will use).

That said, compilation is still monolithic. In the next version, GWT will introduce **incremental compilation**: modules will be pre-compiled on their own, so modules that don't change don't need to be recompiled and only need to be "linked" with the others to produce the final JS.

Comment: when you are talking about modules, it means I should split app to several GWT modules or if I use for example GWTP and building codesplit feature, it is happening automatically?

Comment: Still a concern, so I need to compile all application once before running superDev? if yes, so by changing branch (git), developers should do clean/compile/get:compile then be able to run superDev?

Comment: I am asking previous comment because in my last project (very large) developers never compile client code even once, always run Dev Mode, and it was awesome

Comment: Re. modules: I mean gwt.xml; code splitting is an entirely different thing. Re. compilation, you need to compile once, but then you can change everything but the module name and it should Just Work™; i.e. no need to clean/compile/gwt:compile when switching branches (beware of broken incremental builds though; Maven is broken for instance and you should clean/compile; need for gwt:compile will depend on your dev workflow then)

Comment: Thanks Thomas for replying, personally I prefer classic dev mode and hope to see that on next versions, you think GWT team will support that on next releases ?

Comment: DevMode will probably still be maintained for some time (be it just for IE, whose DevMode works well but dev tools aren't on par with other browsers –e.g. no source maps–, and whose update cycle is slooow). The reason DevMode will be discontinued is not GWT, it's browsers: when your browser will no longer support plugins besides a few whitelisted ones (e.g. Flash), you'll be forced to move to SuperDevMode…

Comment: you said "so modules that don't change don't need to be recompiled", but it needs to be compiled initially!!! yes after super dev is started only changes will be recompiled...

Comment: @Nav onle changed cleasses or changed modules fully?