# gwt 2.7 super Dev mode and incremental compilation

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

In gwt 2.7 we have incremental compilation feature that we are all saying wow, As you know it just compiles last changes.

My concern is when we have a super-super large project we need to wait 30 mins to start super-dev and have initial compilation be done then start to work and use incremental compilation.
Because each time we start super dev mode it creates new folder in tmp directory and compile from  scratch then add change's compiles (Incremental).

So with my understanding it could not be used for large scaled projects, and I believe GWT competitive edge was this otherwise maybe JS frameworks work better like AngularJS.

Please correct me if I am wrong or if there is any plan to have a solution in near future maybe version 3.0

I found -LauncherDir dev parameter added in GWT 2.7, not sure it is using for this purpose or not ...

Thanks

Comment: looks an awful lot like one of your previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387335/gwt-super-dev-mode

Comment: still hoping for the answer....

Comment: do you have an actual problem with the current working of your super dev mode, or is it a general/philosophical question?

Comment: Our current project has million lines of code on front-end so we have to use classic dev mode, our gwt compilation time with GWT2.4 is around 1.5 hours !

Comment: but because dev are using classic dev, they dont need to compile it, it is just happening for staging and compiling by jenkins at midnight.

Comment: Can't you just set the -workDir and -noprecompile?