# GWT plugin for Intellij IDEA

Tags: gwt, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-14

As I see there is no option to do upgrade specific plugin in intellij 14. GWT plugin probably is distributed for GWT 2.6, because in GWT 2.7 we have new super dev mode parameters like -launcherDir that is not in the current Intellij (v14) and  getting "Unknown argument: -launcherDir" error.

So I need to wait for next Intellij IDEA version update or somehow I can upgrade only GWT plugin to support fully GWT2.7 ?

Actually the question would be is this possibl;e to upgrade intellij plugins individually or they will be updated be IDE update ?

Thnx

This is Error log:

```
Unknown argument: -LauncherDir
Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-[no]superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-modulePathPrefix ] [-workDir dir] [-XmethodNameDisplayMode NONE | ONLY_METHOD_NAME | ABBREVIATED | FULL] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.6, 1.7]] [-XjsInteropMode [NONE, JS, CLOSURE]] [-[no]incremental] module[s] 

where 
  -[no]startServer         Starts a servlet container serving the directory specified by the -war flag. (defaults to ON)
  -port                    Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -whitelist               Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist               Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -logdir                  Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel                The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -gen                     Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress             Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort          Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997 for classic Dev Mode or 9876 for Super Dev Mode)
  -[no]superDevMode        Runs Super Dev Mode instead of classic Development Mode. (defaults to ON)
  -server                  Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl              Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war                     The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy                  The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra                   The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
  -modulePathPrefix        The subdirectory inside the war dir where DevMode will create module directories. (defaults empty for top level)
  -workDir                 The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
  -XmethodNameDisplayMode  Emit extra information allow chrome dev tools to display Java identifiers in many places instead of JavaScript functions.
  -sourceLevel             Specifies Java source level (defaults to auto:1.7)
  -XjsInteropMode          Specifies JsInterop mode, either NONE, JS, or CLOSURE (defaults to NONE)
  -[no]incremental         Compiles faster by reusing data from the previous compile. (defaults to ON)
and 
  module[s]                Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA bundled plugins are distributed only together with the product, they are not updated separately.

And actually the GWT plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 14 has been fully updated to support GWT 2.7. What exactly are you doing when you get this error about launcherDir?

Comment: Regarding to release note for GWT 2.7 we have -launcherDir as super dev mode parameters, but when I puit this I get the error, If I run from maven plugin it will pass!

Comment: Where do you put this parameter?

Comment: Run/Debug Configuration (GWT Configuration) window in front of "Dev Mode Parameter"

Comment: The -launcherDir option is accepted by the CodeServer process when you run it separately. IntelliJ IDEA uses the regular DevMode server both in the standard mode and in SuperDevMode, and this server does not accept this option.

Comment: So how can I start it separately in Intellij?

Comment: I guess you can create a run configuration of type Application and point it to the CodeServer main class. However, are you sure you actually need this?

Comment: Not sure, my main question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286492/gwt-2-7-super-dev-mode-and-incremental-compilation

Comment: @yole, what should I do, if I still need `-launcherDir` argument? Is it possible to force intellij to use CodeServer class instead?

Comment: @yole, I'm trying to debug javascript and I've read that I have to start super dev mode from within Intellij. Or can I start super dev mode using gradle and still be able to debug javascript?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually the question would be is this possibl;e to upgrade intellij plugins individually or they will be updated be IDE update ?

It varies. Most bundled plug-ins are only updated when the full IDE itself is updated. Other JetBrains created plug-ins are updated separately. Usually on start-up, there will be a "Plugins ready to update" alert box listing any plug-ins that have updates available. You can also go into the plugin section of the settings and see if any plug-ins have updates available. Any plugins for which an update is available will have an icon indicating such.

What version of IDEA 14 are you running? Issue [IDEA-132009 GWT 2.7.0-beta1 superDevMode doesn't compile](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132009) was [fixed in version 14.0.2](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+14.0.2+Release+Notes) released on December 8. Also issue [IDEA-133522 GWT compile fails in IDEA with GWT 2.7.0](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133522) and [IDEA-133247 GWT Super Dev Mode ignores inherited public folders](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133247) were fixed in v14.0.3 EAP (Early Access Program) build 139.791. You can [download the EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP) or wait for v14.0.3 to be formally released. As a note, I run EAP versions all the time. They are usually very stable. Those fixes may solve your issue.