# Unknown argument: -launcherDir GWT

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm trying to debug in superDevMode using Tomcat instead of Jetty.

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9270Yqt-5I

I added the argument **-launcherDir** to my debug configuration but when I run the configuration I get an unknown arguement error.

**Console Output**

```
    Unknown argument: -launcherDir
Google Web Toolkit 7.1.12
CodeServer [-noprecompile] [-compileTest] [-bindAddress address] [-port port] [-workDir dir] [-allowMissingSrc] [-src dir] [module]

where 
    -noprecompile     Disables pre-compilation of modules.
    -compileTest      Just compile the modules and exit.
    -bindAddress      The ip address of the code server. Defaults to 127.0.0.1.
    -port             The port where the code server will run.
    -workDir          The root of the directory tree where the code server willwrite compiler output. If not supplied, a temporary directorywill be used.
    -allowMissingSrc  Disables the directory existence check for -src flags.
    -src              A directory containing GWT source to be prepended to the classpath for compiling.
and 
module            The GWT modules that the code server should compile. (Example: com.example.MyApp)
```

I noticed a similar question [GWT plugin for Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571296/gwt-plugin-for-intellij-idea) , but I think it went over my head a bit and a fix was not given.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Huh “Google Web Toolkit 7.1.12” ?! Which version are you *actually* using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I came accross this issue, 
Delete the `web.xml` file in the war folder and recreate a blank one 
Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: For this answer to be useful, you should explain **why** that fixed the issue for you.