# How to configure GWT super dev mode for Intellij Idea recent versions 2023

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-super-dev-mode

I was using GWT enterprise application which we package it to war and deploy in Tomcat server in our production. I heard of GWT super dev mode, where we can actually run the application in our local IDE to improve the development activities. I have gone through numerous references but I cannot set it up. Seems there are not much articles to support for configuring super dev mode with recent versions of Intellij IDEA.

Few references I have checked:

- [How to get GWT Super Dev Mode to work with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841301/how-to-get-gwt-super-dev-mode-to-work-with-intellij),
- [GWT Super Dev Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387335/gwt-super-dev-mode?rq=3)
- [how to debug gwt with super dev](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001803699-how-to-debug-gwt-with-super-dev)

project configuration details,

Build management - maven 3.8.4
java JDK - 1.8
GWT version - 2.9.0

Kindly let me know for any working references/leads.

Comment: What GWT version are you using? and how are you managing the project (maven, gradle, etc)?

Comment: Hi @IgnacioBaca, I was using maven as my build management tool, Java JDK 1.8 and GWT version 2.9.0

Comment: Is your code separated in client-, server- & share with own maven modules or all in one? Which GWT-MAVEN-PLUGIN are you using?

Comment: Yes, my codebae use client and server package structure and a common shared package used by both client and server side code. Also they both share the same maven modules.  I was using `org.codehaus.mojo: gwt-maven-plugin`

Comment: Switch to this one: net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin and follow the instructions from here: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin